# Network button missing gone from Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, samba

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS.

I remember having a link in Nautilus that I used to browse network shares with in the past. I don't remember exactly but I think it was "Windows network" or "Browse network".

Now I can't find this on my current installation, there's only "Connect to server", but this is not what I want. Is there a way to put that link there?

Answer (score 4):

[image]

On my 16.04 *Network* is between *Trash* and *Computer* in the left. It has *Windows Network* inside.

If it really missed - you can reinstall `gvfs-backends` with

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gvfs-backends
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're right, the feature is called "Browse Network" and it was reported [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1552000).

[image: Browse Network in Nautilus]

While they work on a fix, maybe you can try the following:

1. Click on `Connect to Server` and in the requested Server Address write: `network://`

[image]

2. Press Connect and the "Windows Network" will show up on the folder.
   [image]

Also you can try to reinstall the package:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gvfs-backends -y
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Interesting. I can actually type the location network:/// and than I see the Windows Network icon, but clicking it pups up an error: "Failed to retrieve share list from server: No such file or directory"